# how to upload a file on a mysql server if access to temp folder is not present

Tags: mysql, windows

I have a CSV file that i want to enter into a table in my database which is present on a remote server. But presently I don't have access to temp folder so I cannot copy my file on that folder. Is there a way I can upload file from any random folder onto the database?

This is my command in sql server:

```
load data local  infile 'C:/Users/trainee_aiyer/Downloads/cash_ord.csv' into table cm_ord fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

and my file path is this:

```
C:\Users\trainee_aiyer\Downloads\cash_ord.csv
```

I switched '\' to '/' as the prior was causing syntax errors. but I get an error saying

```
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'C:/Users/trainee_aiyer/cash_ord.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

Comment: @jkavalik when using local file should be in temp folder right ? , because i tried that and it's not working for any arbitrary path

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get some specific error message or just unexpected results? What is the exact statement? (you can *sanitize* paths and some identifiers, but please keep as much as possible intact)

Comment: @jkavalik it says it could not find my file , but the path is exactly the same

Comment: Please be specific - exact error message may be needed (maybe even containing an error code) to find out what is the problem. You are not allowed to access the `/tmp/` on your local computer?

Comment: `(Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")` - that is not any mysql error about rights.. sounds like you just have some typo or something in your path - please add the full `load data infile ... ` statement you try to run and the `ls` and `pwd` for the dir the file is in. [edit] your question instead writing comments.

Comment: Yous should have mentioned in the beginning that you work with Windows - what about replacing `\ ` with `\\ ` instead of `/` ?

Comment: @jkavalik still the same response

Comment: if the file is at `C:\Users\trainee_aiyer\Downloads\cash_ord.csv` and the error tell you 'C:\Users\trainee_aiyer\cash_ord.csv' was not found then there is something wrong for sure, missing one directory level.

Comment: And your command is missing the `LOCAL` keyword anyway..

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), it seems it is not possible, since it is operating systems temporary directory and not it is not configured in MySQL.

> When using LOCAL with LOAD DATA, a copy of the file is created in the
>   server's temporary directory. This is not the directory determined by
>   the value of tmpdir or slave_load_tmpdir, but rather the operating
>   system's temporary directory, and is not configurable in the MySQL
>   Server. (Typically the system temporary directory is /tmp on Linux
>   systems and C:\WINDOWS\TEMP on Windows.) Lack of sufficient space for
>   the copy in this directory can cause the LOAD DATA LOCAL statement to
>   fail.

Alternative, you may try with [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_local) with `local` parameter, but make sure, you have `access` to that directory, else you may encounter an error. I hope this answer will help you. Thank you.

Comment: That temp file should be created by the server and the user rights should have no effect on the operation.

Comment: i had read somewhere to upload a file onto a remote server you need to have your file in the temp folder while using local , is it false ?

Comment: @avz2611 I think it is false in general, but there may be some problems with rights etc. For example Apparmor may block the mysql binaries to read any other dir for security reasons so tmp would be the best bet in most cases. For the record I can hardly believe that your user account would even work properly without /tmp/ access being allowed as lot of apps expect and use it (but I may be wrong).